# Keep python script running after ssh closed

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen, nohup

I am trying to run a script called `script.py` on a remote CentOS 7.3 box that I ssh into. I am running the script from an environment called `py`. I want the script to continue running after I disconnect. From reading other stack exchange questions I have tried

```
conda activate py
nohup python script.py &
```

This works, but when I disconnect the ssh the process stops running.

I have also tried

```
screen
conda activate py
python script.py
```

However, this gives me a `NameError` pertaining to a function in a module that is in my `py` environment but not in `base`. So it looks like when I use `screen` its not using the `py` environment.

Finally I do not have `tmux` installed and cannot do so as it is a work box.

Any other ideas?

Comment: can you change python code ?

Comment: Just activate the python environment _after_ running `screen`. Doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `setsid`. I used it for a python script running a WSGI.
Per [tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/):

> Another utility to achieve the required behavior is setsid. Nohup has
> a disadvantage in the sense that the process group of the process
> remains the same so the process running with nohup is vulnerable to
> any signal sent to the whole process group (like Ctrl + C).
>
> setsid on other hand allocates a new process group to the process
> being executed and hence, the process created is totally in a newly
> allocated process group and can execute safely without fear of being
> killed even after session logout.

Answer (score -1):

This usually works for me,

```
python script.py &
```

In your case try without **nohup**, This should work.

Comment: This may work in specific cases, but very often won't. When you close the ssh connection, the child processes will also be closed.